# Notification using bluetoothctl output

Tags: bash, sound, bluetooth, notification

I am using 22.04 and I created a bash script to disconnect my Bluetooth speaker. You can see the code below

```
#!/bin/sh
bluetoothctl disconnect macID

notify-send "Soundbar Disconnected!"
```

While it works great for my needs as I have it as a desktop shortcut, it is a one-click disconnect for me now.

I was wondering whether I can display the output message of the `bluetootctl` command instead of the predefined text. ie, if there is no speaker connected, the output will be different.

I tried `echo blutoothctl.output`, which didn't work. Would be nice to have some help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Terse answer:

`$ man bash` then type
`/Command\ Substitution` to find the description for `$(...)`, and
`/Special\ Parameters` for `$?`

```
$ . /etc/os-release; echo $NAME $VERSION  # if that matters
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)

$ saved="$(bluetoothctl connect 00:09:DD:10:48:F9)"

$ echo $?
1

$ echo $saved
Attempting to connect to 00:09:DD:10:48:F9 [CHG] Device 00:09:DD:10:48:F9 Connected: yes [CHG] Device 00:09:DD:10:48:F9 ServicesResolved: yes Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable

$ echo $saved | od -t x1z
0000000 41 74 74 65 6d 70 74 69 6e 67 20 74 6f 20 63 6f  >Attempting to co<
0000020 6e 6e 65 63 74 20 74 6f 20 30 30 3a 30 39 3a 44  >nnect to 00:09:D<
0000040 44 3a 31 30 3a 34 38 3a 46 39 20 5b 01 1b 5b 30  >D:10:48:F9 [..[0<
0000060 3b 39 33 6d 02 43 48 47 01 1b 5b 30 6d 02 5d 20  >;93m.CHG..[0m.] <
0000100 44 65 76 69 63 65 20 30 30 3a 30 39 3a 44 44 3a  >Device 00:09:DD:<
0000120 31 30 3a 34 38 3a 46 39 20 43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74  >10:48:F9 Connect<
0000140 65 64 3a 20 79 65 73 20 5b 01 1b 5b 30 3b 39 33  >ed: yes [..[0;93<
0000160 6d 02 43 48 47 01 1b 5b 30 6d 02 5d 20 44 65 76  >m.CHG..[0m.] Dev<
0000200 69 63 65 20 30 30 3a 30 39 3a 44 44 3a 31 30 3a  >ice 00:09:DD:10:<
0000220 34 38 3a 46 39 20 53 65 72 76 69 63 65 73 52 65  >48:F9 ServicesRe<
0000240 73 6f 6c 76 65 64 3a 20 79 65 73 20 46 61 69 6c  >solved: yes Fail<
0000260 65 64 20 74 6f 20 63 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74 3a 20 6f  >ed to connect: o<
0000300 72 67 2e 62 6c 75 65 7a 2e 45 72 72 6f 72 2e 4e  >rg.bluez.Error.N<
0000320 6f 74 41 76 61 69 6c 61 62 6c 65 0a              >otAvailable.<
0000334

$
```

Answer (score 0):

managed to use a function and then assigned the output to a variable. Then echo and notify-send works

```
#!/bin/sh

myoutput () {

bluetoothctl disconnect macID

}


myoutput

VAR=$(myoutput)

echo "${VAR} , is the output"

notify-send "${VAR} | Soundbar Disconnected!"
```